# Null type of ref in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an array of inputs in react and they need to be able to communicate with each other's DOM through a Ref, simple enough. I wrote something like this:

```
export default function SomeArray(){
  const inputsRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement[]>([])

  return <>{[1,2,3].map((_,i) => (
    <input ref={el => inputsRef.current[i] = el} />
  )}</>
}
```

Now, the only problem comes from the type. Namely, `el` is `HTMLInputElement | null`. As simple it would be to include null in Ref typing, my question is: How can it be null? Is it some lifecycle quirk? Because, as I understand correctly, the ref is being used only after the element is actually created and as such the reference should already be held towards a DOM element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the element is removed, React will call the ref callback with the value `null`.

See the [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback):

> Instead of a ref object (like the one returned by `useRef`), you may pass a function to the ref attribute.
>
> ```
> <div ref={(node) => console.log(node)} />
> ```
>
> When the <div> DOM node is added to the screen, React will call your ref callback with the DOM node as the argument. When that <div> DOM node is removed, React will call your ref callback with null.